# Get Notifications from Google chat web to android

Tags: google-account, google-hangouts, push-notifications

I use a work account on google chat on web. But Google suite of that account dosnt have Google Chat/Hangout app for android. And as far as I know, Google chat only gives me push notification on web.
Is there any way I can directly recieive Gchat notifications from my work account to my android device Directly ?